# Is my infant not feeding enough and sleeping too much?

Tags: infant, feeding

Our baby boy is 11 days old and the last 2 days has been feeding 5-6 hours apart and sleeping between. He feeds for about 10-15 min on each breast and sometimes takes up to an hour to get back to sleep. Should I be worried that he is not getting enough milk and too much sleep?

Comment: If a child gains weight and hits his milestones then generally they get enough food.

Answer (score 4):

This actually sounds fairly normal to me (they pretty much sleep the first couple of weeks), although the frequency of eating seems slightly lower than average.  Talk to your pediatrician.

You might also make it a habit to keep track of when and how much he is eating.  It is hard to keep track when breast feeding of exactly how much he is getting, but I would suggest keeping a log of how much (if you can) and how long (if you can't measure how much).

Again, my main suggestion is to just place a call to your ped's doc and ask the question.